# Fetch currencies from a website and return as a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, urllib

I am trying to write a module that fetches the currencies list from [open exchange rates](http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json) and returns it as a dictionary. I've tried playing around with the `urllib` module but my knowledge is limited.

This is all I have so far:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json')
html = response.read()
print(html)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have in your `html` variable is a JSON string. Just parse it to convert to a dictionary:

```
import json
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json')
html = response.read().decode("utf-8")

my_dict = json.loads(html)
print my_dict
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.                                                                                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\daniel\Documents\Python Scripts\untitled22.py", line 5, in <module>
    my_dict = json.loads(html)
  File "C:\Users\daniel\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'   (have i done something wrong?)

Comment: Sorry, it has to be decoded to utf-8. See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want the currencies list this should do it:

```
import urllib
response = urllib.urlopen('http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json')
html = response.read()
print(html)
```

This is what I get:

```
{
    "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
    "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
    "AMD": "Armenian Dram",
    "ANG": "Netherlands Antillean Guilder",
    "AOA": "Angolan Kwanza",
    "ARS": "Argentine Peso",
    "AUD": "Australian Dollar",
    "AWG": "Aruban Florin", 
    "AZN": "Azerbaijani Manat",
    "BAM": "Bosnia-Herzegovina Convertible Mark",
    "BBD": "Barbadian Dollar",
    "BDT": "Bangladeshi Taka",
    "BGN": "Bulgarian Lev",
    "BHD": "Bahraini Dinar",
    "BIF": "Burundian Franc",
    "BMD": "Bermudan Dollar",
    "BND": "Brunei Dollar",
    "BOB": "Bolivian Boliviano",
    "BRL": "Brazilian Real",
    "BSD": "Bahamian Dollar",
    "BTC": "Bitcoin",
    "BTN": "Bhutanese Ngultrum",
    "BWP": "Botswanan Pula",
    "BYR": "Belarusian Ruble",
    "BZD": "Belize Dollar",
    "CAD": "Canadian Dollar",
    "CDF": "Congolese Franc",
    "CHF": "Swiss Franc",
    "CLF": "Chilean Unit of Account (UF)",
    "CLP": "Chilean Peso",
    "CNY": "Chinese Yuan",
    "COP": "Colombian Peso",
    "CRC": "Costa Rican Col籀n",
    "CUC": "Cuban Convertible Peso",
    "CUP": "Cuban Peso",
    "CVE": "Cape Verdean Escudo",
    "CZK": "Czech Republic Koruna",
    "DJF": "Djiboutian Franc",
    "DKK": "Danish Krone",
    "DOP": "Dominican Peso",
    "DZD": "Algerian Dinar",
    "EEK": "Estonian Kroon",
    "EGP": "Egyptian Pound",
    "ERN": "Eritrean Nakfa",
    "ETB": "Ethiopian Birr",
    "EUR": "Euro",
    "FJD": "Fijian Dollar",
    "FKP": "Falkland Islands Pound",
    "GBP": "British Pound Sterling",
    "GEL": "Georgian Lari",
    "GGP": "Guernsey Pound",
    "GHS": "Ghanaian Cedi",
    "GIP": "Gibraltar Pound",
    "GMD": "Gambian Dalasi",
    "GNF": "Guinean Franc",
    "GTQ": "Guatemalan Quetzal",
    "GYD": "Guyanaese Dollar",
    "HKD": "Hong Kong Dollar",
    "HNL": "Honduran Lempira",
    "HRK": "Croatian Kuna",
    "HTG": "Haitian Gourde",
    "HUF": "Hungarian Forint",
    "IDR": "Indonesian Rupiah",
    "ILS": "Israeli New Sheqel",
    "IMP": "Manx pound",
    "INR": "Indian Rupee",
    "IQD": "Iraqi Dinar",
    "IRR": "Iranian Rial",
    "ISK": "Icelandic Kr籀na",
    "JEP": "Jersey Pound",
    "JMD": "Jamaican Dollar",
    "JOD": "Jordanian Dinar",
    "JPY": "Japanese Yen",
    "KES": "Kenyan Shilling",
    "KGS": "Kyrgystani Som",
    "KHR": "Cambodian Riel",
    "KMF": "Comorian Franc",
    "KPW": "North Korean Won",
    "KRW": "South Korean Won",
    "KWD": "Kuwaiti Dinar",
    "KYD": "Cayman Islands Dollar",
    "KZT": "Kazakhstani Tenge",
    "LAK": "Laotian Kip",
    "LBP": "Lebanese Pound",
    "LKR": "Sri Lankan Rupee",
    "LRD": "Liberian Dollar",
    "LSL": "Lesotho Loti",
    "LTL": "Lithuanian Litas",
    "LVL": "Latvian Lats",
    "LYD": "Libyan Dinar",
    "MAD": "Moroccan Dirham",
    "MDL": "Moldovan Leu",
    "MGA": "Malagasy Ariary",
    "MKD": "Macedonian Denar",
    "MMK": "Myanma Kyat",
    "MNT": "Mongolian Tugrik",
    "MOP": "Macanese Pataca",
    "MRO": "Mauritanian Ouguiya",
    "MTL": "Maltese Lira",
    "MUR": "Mauritian Rupee",
    "MVR": "Maldivian Rufiyaa",
    "MWK": "Malawian Kwacha",
    "MXN": "Mexican Peso",
    "MYR": "Malaysian Ringgit",
    "MZN": "Mozambican Metical",
    "NAD": "Namibian Dollar",
    "NGN": "Nigerian Naira",
    "NIO": "Nicaraguan C籀rdoba",
    "NOK": "Norwegian Krone",
    "NPR": "Nepalese Rupee",
    "NZD": "New Zealand Dollar",
    "OMR": "Omani Rial",
    "PAB": "Panamanian Balboa",
    "PEN": "Peruvian Nuevo Sol",
    "PGK": "Papua New Guinean Kina",
    "PHP": "Philippine Peso",
    "PKR": "Pakistani Rupee",
    "PLN": "Polish Zloty",
    "PYG": "Paraguayan Guarani",
    "QAR": "Qatari Rial",
    "RON": "Romanian Leu",
    "RSD": "Serbian Dinar",
    "RUB": "Russian Ruble",
    "RWF": "Rwandan Franc",
    "SAR": "Saudi Riyal",
    "SBD": "Solomon Islands Dollar",
    "SCR": "Seychellois Rupee",
    "SDG": "Sudanese Pound",
    "SEK": "Swedish Krona",
    "SGD": "Singapore Dollar",
    "SHP": "Saint Helena Pound",
    "SLL": "Sierra Leonean Leone",
    "SOS": "Somali Shilling",
    "SRD": "Surinamese Dollar",
    "STD": "S瓊o Tom矇 and Pr穩ncipe Dobra",
    "SVC": "Salvadoran Col籀n",
    "SYP": "Syrian Pound",
    "SZL": "Swazi Lilangeni",
    "THB": "Thai Baht",
    "TJS": "Tajikistani Somoni",
    "TMT": "Turkmenistani Manat",
    "TND": "Tunisian Dinar",
    "TOP": "Tongan Pa妡anga",
    "TRY": "Turkish Lira",
    "TTD": "Trinidad and Tobago Dollar",
    "TWD": "New Taiwan Dollar",
    "TZS": "Tanzanian Shilling",
    "UAH": "Ukrainian Hryvnia",
    "UGX": "Ugandan Shilling",
    "USD": "United States Dollar",
    "UYU": "Uruguayan Peso",
    "UZS": "Uzbekistan Som",
    "VEF": "Venezuelan Bol穩var Fuerte",
    "VND": "Vietnamese Dong",
    "VUV": "Vanuatu Vatu",
    "WST": "Samoan Tala",
    "XAF": "CFA Franc BEAC",
    "XAG": "Silver (troy ounce)",
    "XAU": "Gold (troy ounce)",
    "XCD": "East Caribbean Dollar",
    "XDR": "Special Drawing Rights",
    "XOF": "CFA Franc BCEAO",
    "XPF": "CFP Franc",
    "YER": "Yemeni Rial",
    "ZAR": "South African Rand",
    "ZMK": "Zambian Kwacha (pre-2013)",
    "ZMW": "Zambian Kwacha",
    "ZWL": "Zimbabwean Dollar"
}
```

Comment: I need it to be returned as a dictionary

Comment: @DannyGoodall it should be a dictionary, pls run my code and check

Comment: Thank You, im on Python 3 so changes your code slightly but all gravy now.

Comment: @DannyGoodall I updated my answer to show you what I get. I am not sure why you are getting an error msg. For me it works fine and returns the above dictionary with the currencies list.

Comment: @JoeR This is not a dictionary, it is a JSON string which _looks like_ a dictionary. Also your code only works for Python 2.x while the OP is using Python 3.

Comment: @DannyGoodall Yes, thats what I thought, I am on Python 2.7 so that was the issue, but happy to hear that its working for you now. So if my answer works for you pls mark it as the right answer.